# Undefined method error but method is defined in Ruby... why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am unable to call any methods on a renderer class I wrote. Should its methods not be exposed?

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    BaseRenderer.renderer_for(@entry) # @entry is loaded with a before_filter
  end
end

# app/renderers/base_renderer.rb
class BaseRenderer
  def renderer_for(entry)
    klass ||= "#{entry.entry_type}Renderer".constantize
    klass.new(entry)
  end
end
```

I get `NoMethodError at ... undefined method 'renderer_for' for BaseRenderer:Class`

But the method is clearly defined. What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean a class method, then

```
def renderer_for(entry)
```

should be

```
def self.renderer_for(entry)
```

Or

```
class BaseRenderer
  class << self
    def renderer_for(entry)
      # could also change to this
      Object.const_get("#{entry.entry_type}Renderer").new(entry)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Duhh, of course! I'm calling an instance method on class initialisation! Silly me!

Comment: xdazz, could you explain the benefit of using `class << self`. Is it just so we could kind of group all of our class methods and have them in one place?

Comment: @Mohamad, have you got `articlesRenderer` class?

Comment: @Zippie Both way has its benefit depends on which you like.

Comment: @xdazz -- I realize this is out of the scope of the question, I can't call `render` inside my `ArticlesRenderer` class. Why is that?     `render template: 'article'` results in `undefined method 'render' for #<ArticlesRenderer:0x007fe7292ca818>` I have to include the controller `render` method in my class?

Comment: @Mohamad Because `render` is not an instance method of your `ArticlesRenderer` class but `ApplicationController`.